# Adjust the size of a report (Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I'm using Access 2010.  I created a report and I'm trying to reduce its length but  I can't find option like that in the properties.

If I try to resize it in design mode, it doesn't work.  When I change to 'report view', the size changes again.

How can I adjust the size of the report?

Comment: Can you provide some screenshots of your report in Design View?  There are a lot of things that contribute to the final size of a report, such as spacing between groups/records and above/below the headers/footers.

Comment: yes. this is the design view:
http://s24.postimage.org/s5qx5zbw3/report2.jpg
and this is the real size:
http://s15.postimage.org/jyvt484mh/report1.jpg

(i want to reduce it)

Comment: I understand your desire to protect your business property, but it's a little hard to see what's going on with everything whited out.  What exactly are you trying to reduce the length of?  Is there just extra white-space?  Or are you wanting to combine content in some way to take up less space?

Comment: At first glance, you could reduce some of the space at the bottom of the Detail section (by clicking the top of "Page Footer" and dragging it up).  When each row section of the report is generated, it exactly copies the contents of the Detail section for each record, preserving every pixel of layout and whitespace.

Comment: ok thanks. i did that. it help with 1-2cm. but i still have a lot of white space. what more can i do?

Comment: A one-page report is going to render to the size of selected paper size, regardless of the data on the report. Sure, you can scale the report, but it will also scale the data. Do you want to just show these fields on-screen? If so, you are mis-using the Report.